# Doctype returned from Server instead of String?

Tags: android, django, bitnami

I'm using BitNami to test my django project. I'm creating a connection from android, passing to it a url to fetch some data from the database. The data is in this form:

```
{"apps": ["False", "Hello from notepade++", "My App", "Test"]}
```

here's how I'm fetching and receiving the data in android

```
public static ArrayList<String> getApps(){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse responseCategories;
    int categoriesStatusCode =0;
    String responseCategoriesString = "";
    ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
    HttpGet httpgetCategories = new HttpGet("http://safwany/sampleproject/applications/fetch_apps");
    try {
        responseCategories = httpclient.execute(httpgetCategories);
        categoriesStatusCode = responseCategories.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        try {
            responseCategoriesString = EntityUtils.toString(responseCategories.getEntity());
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(categoriesStatusCode==200){
        JSONObject object;
        try {
            System.out.println(responseCategoriesString);
            object = new JSONObject(responseCategoriesString);
            JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("apps");
            for(int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++)
            {
                String s = (String) Jarray.get(i);
                out.add(s);
                //categoriesMap.put(s, 0);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return out;
}
```

When I try to print responseCategoriesString, I get the following:

```
04-01 22:55:56.335: I/System.out(9325): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://search.tedata.net/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=eg&ParticipantID=esrkzqp9pwh62lmydaf4wsy3i92taus2&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsafwany%2Fsampleproject%2Fapplications%2Ffetch_apps&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0"/><script type="text/javascript">url="http://search.tedata.net/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=eg&ParticipantID=esrkzqp9pwh62lmydaf4wsy3i92taus2&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsafwany%2Fsampleproject%2Fapplications%2Ffetch_apps&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0";if(top.location!=location){var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,b=d.body,x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||b.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||b.clientHeight;url+="&w="+x+"&h="+y;}window.location.replace(url);</script></head><body></body></html>
04-01 22:55:56.335: W/System.err(9325): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: As you can see: you get html back instead of json. So somehow your server does return wrong data or you are not requesting correctly. When you have created the django part as well, check there for errors too and debug why the request you send returns wrong data.

Comment: this is the view in django
def fetch_apps(request):
    apps = App.objects.all()
    apps_array = []
    for a in apps:
        apps_array.append(a.name)
    apps_array.sort()
    res = json.dumps({"apps":apps_array})
    return HttpResponse(res, mimetype='application/json')

I think it's correct as when I try the url in the browser, it fetches all of the data correctly

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the response data you get I think you have trouble with some firewall or similar:

```
http://search.tedata.net/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=eg&ParticipantID=esrkzqp9pwh62lmydaf4wsy3i92taus2&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsafwany%2Fsampleproject%2Fapplications%2Ffetch_apps&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0
```

Contains your requested url:

```
FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fsafwany%2Fsampleproject%2Fapplications%2Ffetch_apps
```

But `FailedURI` sounds like a company firefall/gateway with filter... you should check if your emulator/device can really access the `safwany` "domain". Maybe you should try an IP instead of `safwany`?

Comment: I'm accessing from real device not emulator. When I tried ip, localhost or anything like that the connection is always refused

Comment: Still the questions remains: does the WIFI your device is connected to has the information which IP is behind `safwany`? Does your local network DNS know that?`I doubt that.

Comment: Could you explain a little more?!

Comment: Where does this `safwany` comes from? Can you access this url from your device? If you don't get what I mean, ask the one who has given you this link and/or read about DNS.

Comment: safwany was created when I installed bitnami. I'm trying to make server instead of localhost as whenever I try accessing localhost from android device, connection is refused

Comment: Well localhost on an android device is the device itself. Your problem is not the code but the infrastructure. You should configure your server to accept requests from everybody. Than you can use the IP address of your PC/Server. swafwany will only be usable by your own pc, so you could try running your app on the emulator, too.